# JQuery $.getJSON call not formatting dropdown list

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am new to ajax calls, and am attempting to get a trivial example working, to
populate a country dropdown list.  I have verified that I am getting back data
from the call, but having trouble actually populating the dropdown list.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadlist(selobj,url,nameattr)
{
    $(selobj).empty();
    $.getJSON(url,{},function(data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(i,obj)
        {
           $(selobj).append($('<option></option>').val(obj[nameattr]).html(obj[nameattr]));
        });
    });
}

$(function()
{ 
   loadlist($('select#country').get(0), 'http://127.0.0.1/country1.php','country');
});
</script>
</head>

    <body>
        Country:<select name='country' id='country' size='1'></select>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the country1.php file:

```
<?php  
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
 header('Content-type: application/json');  
 $output = '{  
  "  " : "  ",  
  "US" : "United States",  
  "AF" : "Afghanistan",  
  "AL" : "Albania",  
  "DZ" : "Algeria",  
  "AS" : "American Samoa",  
  "AD" : "Andorra",  
  "AO" : "Angola",  
  ...  
  "ZM" : "Zambia",  
  "ZW" : "Zimbabwe" }';  
 echo $output;  

 ?>
```

What do I need to do to get a normal dropdown?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: try to console.log your obj inside your each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think val() works for `<option>` tags; it's to get/ set the value of a control, such as SELECT or INPUT, not really to edit an option.

Try setting the OPTION value by means of `attr('value', someValue)` instead. I also think your expectation of jQuery.each() on an object ("map") is wrong.

If your above code is mostly working:

```
    var dest = $(selobj);
    console.log('populating data to options', data, dest.length);
    $.each( data, function(key,value) {
        console.log('  option', key, value);
        var el = $('<option></option>')
            .attr('value', key)
            .html( value);
        dest.append( el);
    });
```

More logging, and assigning major repeatedly-used & intermediate variables (both for performance, and so you can log/debug them) is also a good thing.

Comment: I got this approach to work, and it is useful to see how you use the intermediate variable approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `obj[nameattr]` where `nameattr` is country. If you notice, there is no property of your `obj`

May I suggest using `for in` loop instead of `$.each`

```
for(var key in data) {
    $(selobj).append($('<option></option>').val(key).html(data[key]));
}
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion - with a minor addition of a closed paren at the end, it works great.  I also understand this approach.

Answer (score 0):

i would make it simple:

```
    $.each(data, function(i,obj)
    {
       $(selobj).append('<option value="' + obj[nameattr] +'">' + obj[nameattr] + '</option>');
    });
```